# spark structured streaming from kafka consumer poll timeout expiration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, consumer

```
spark 3.2.1  
hadoop 3.3.0  
kafka 2.5.0 
scala 2.12.12
```

kafka cluster = 12 VMs = 12 nodes

there are 2 topics, each with 48 partitions

I run spark structured streaming reading stream from kafka, consuming both topics at once.

I have 32 executors, each with 3 cores.

```
val options: Map[String, String] = Map(
  "kafka.bootstrap.servers" -> "ip1:9092,ip2:9092,...,ip12:9092",
  "subscribe" -> "topic1,topic2",
  "startingOffsets" -> "latest,
  "maxOffsetsPerTrigger" -> "1000000,
  "failOnDataLoss" -> "false",
  "minPartitions" -> "48",
  )

spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(options).load()
```

The spark job does aggregation of the data also once it consumed the stream. I have used various number of spark partitions/tasks and `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` in the past. I have never had problems with this spark job with consumption from kafka.

Just recently, the spark job started lagging. When I deployed two other test jobs consuming from these topics they experienced same issue.

The issue is that one small task is taking long time. While on average all small tasks completes in few seconds this specific one can take 2-3 min or even longer.

setting:

```
"spark.speculation": "true"
"spark.speculation.quantile": "0.95"
```

helps spark to retry the long running small task but does not resolve the issue at its source.

I did thread dump and can see:

```
KafkaDataConsumer.fetchData
```

I assume this small task is spending most of its time polling data from kafka / waiting for data from kafka.

I also see in spark driver logs:

```
23/03/23 07:39:49 WARN ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-f5eb76a4-710b-4b71-b2db-cca5e0b53cfa--1690060917-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-f5eb76a4-710b-4b71-b2db-cca5e0b53cfa--1690060917-driver-0] consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

I only have this config in spark:

```
"spark.executor.heartbeatInterval": "10s"
"spark.network.timeoutInterval": "20s"
"spark.storage.blockManagerHeartbeatTimeoutMs": "20s"
```

I wonder why the problem occured and how to fix it?

[image]
[image]
[image]